# firefox addone SDK: basic extension: what is the {} for?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

```
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");
```

**what is the {} for ?**

Looks like panels do not need that

```
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 180,
  height: 180,
  contentURL: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jetpack&useformat=mobile"
});
```

Comment: It's destructor method of ES6. Its not a firefox specific thing.